# How to find a div element inside the row table and return the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table below which row is being looped by foreach statement. Inside the table, there are various div elements as you can see. I want to get and return the value of one of the div element with a **class="divrep"** by clicking the button with a **class ="postrep"**. I tried something below but it returns null object so I'm not sure if I get the right div element.

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
           $('.postrep').click(function () {
               var findiv = $(this).closest('table').find('div[class="divrep"]');
               alert(findiv.toString());

            });
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="mytable">  

    <tr >
        <td class="tdstyle" >

  <div style="font-weight:bold;">  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) </div> 

   <p >  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment) </p>
  <p> <input type="button" id="like" name="like" value="Like" style="color:blue;border:0px;background-color:inherit;cursor:pointer" /> <input type="button" class ="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)" /></p>                                                                                                                                 
  <div id="divReply" class ="divrep"> I want to return this string value...

     <div> 
        <div class="editor-field" style="display:none; margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px">  
          <input type="text" id="comidvalue" name="id" class="id" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" />
        </div>

        <br />
        <input type="text" id="namerep" name="name" class="name" style="width:445px;resize:none" />

       <br />
       <textarea id="reply" name="reply" class="reply" style="width:445px;height:100px;resize:none" ></textarea>

         <br />

        <input type="button" class="postrep" value="Post Reply" name="butname" style="cursor:pointer" /> 
      </div>
            <br />

  </div>

        </td>       
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `.contents()` to grab the text nodes as well as the child elements and get the first element from the returned collecion,

```
$('.postrep').click(function () {
    var findiv = $(this).closest('.divrep');
    alert(findiv.contents()[0].nodeValue);
});
```

Using `.text()` over the `finddiv` object would be recommended, but if suppose you have more text nodes inside of `finddiv` then prefer this solution.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xLvxdyta/)

Answer (score 1):

What about this way?

```
        $(function () {
           $('.postrep').click(function () {
               var findiv = $(this).closest('.divrep');
               alert(findiv.html());

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL48aqgw/) 
just change the api as

```
alert(findiv.text());
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

for select the dive with class **divrep** the selector is ".divrep" and in addintion per return the content of the node you must use the api html if you want inner [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or the api text if you wont the content as simply [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
var findiv = $(this).closest('table').find('.divrep');
 alert(findiv.html());
```